# 'delTodo' is not defined. React (line 51)

Tags: reactjs

Error:

> 'delTodo' is not defined. React (line 51)

I am new to React. Here is the code; what did I do wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import markComplete from './components/Todos'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          key: 1,
          title: 'Take out the trash',
          completed:false
        },
        {`enter code here`
          key: 2,
          title: 'Dinner with wife',
          completed:true`enter code here`
        },
        {
          key: 3,
          title: 'Meeting with boss',
          completed:false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  asd = () =>{

  }
    // Toggle Complete
  markComplete = (key) => {
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.map(todo=> {
      if(todo.key === key) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo;
    }) });
  }

  //Delete Todo
  delTodo = (key) => {
    console.log(key)
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todos todos={this.state.todos} markComplete={markComplete}
      delTodo={delTodo} />     
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a class component, you need to use the `this` keyword when you refer to class attributes (state, methods, etc.). So the method should be `this.delTodo`:

```js
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Todos 
      todos={this.state.todos}
      markComplete={this.markComplete}
      delTodo={this.delTodo}
    />     
  </div>
)
```